# Why my directive in AngularJs is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 3 files: the product-title.html, the index.html calling the product-title and the app.js where I create my directive.
My browser is not showing the code on product-title.html

product-title.html

```
<h3>
  {{product.name}}
  <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em>
</h3>
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="gemStore">
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="list-group" ng-controller="StoreController as store">
  <div class="list-group-item cuerpo" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
   <product-title></product-title>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.products = gems;
});

app.directive('productTitle', function(){
   return {
     restrict: "E",
     templateUrl: "product-title.html"
   };
});
})();
```

gems is an array of objects with their names, price etc.
The code was working just fine untill I tried to create the first directive.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your debugger?  Any network errors?

Comment: In the controller you've written  this.products = gems; what is gems here? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Try importing $scope in the controller and doing $scope.products = gems;

Comment: Too many unknowns without us asking 20 questions.

Comment: I found th answer, it is because of chrome doesn't let me run files locally but it works fine on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

May Help you.

```
<html ng-app="gemStore">
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="list-group" ng-controller="StoreController">
  <div class="list-group-item cuerpo" ng-repeat="product in products">
   <product-title></product-title>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

JS Code:

```
var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
app.controller('StoreController', function($scope){
    var gems = [       
                {name: "LIVKR-2015", price: 20},
                {name: "LIVHCC-2015", price: 22},
                {name: "LIKKCC-2015", price: 24},
                {name: "LICPCC-2015", price: 20},
                {name: "LMLHCC-2015", price: 20}
                ];
    $scope.products = gems;                 
});
app.directive('productTitle', function(){
   return {
     restrict: "E",
     templateUrl: "product-title.html"
   };
});
```